# Hidraw udev rule group sometimes failes

Tags: usb, docker, udev

I have troubles with a sensor that acts as a hidraw device to send periodic data through USB.
I have a Udev rule that creates a symlink to be used by docker container with Azure IoT Edge.

```
SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1a86", ATTRS{idProduct}=="e025", SYMLINK+="temper" MODE="0660"
```

Thing is, usually, after some time (may be minutes or hours), it starts writing on screen and docker can't detect it anymore (program sends error).

I've already tried to set GROUP="docker" in the udev rule. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with LXDE.

Device is TemperHUM:
https://www.amazon.fr/Temp%C3%A9rature-Dordinateur-Enregistreur-Thermo-hygrom%C3%A8tre-Surveillance/dp/B0B7SJL3C7/ref=sr_1_5
Hope the link works

Comment: Is the udev rule even involved past the initial step of recognizing the device and adding the symlink? The symptom you describe makes me wonder if the device is switching into "TXT" mode - see [Getting USB TEMPer2 temperature sensor readings into Prometheus (on Linux)](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/USBTemper2SensorToPrometheus)

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for replying, and sorry for delay, didn't receive the notification. When it happens, the symlink is still available but the docker container cannot access it anymore, just like another process was taking the hand on the root of the symlink

Comment: @steeldriver and for the suggestion, I have the blue version (not the red one, maybe it works differently), the error happens at any moment, I never touch the button. But when I press on it it stops outputting so nothing is being written on the screen anymore, obviously. And if a re-press, everything on screen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited the udev rule to this:

```
KERNEL=="hidraw*", SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1a86", ATTRS{idProduct}=="e025", SYMLINK+="temper", OWNER="iotedge", GROUP="iotedge", MODE="0660"
```

(Added KERNEL, OWNER and GROUP)

That seems to be better, it's been two days running without issue (best I had before was 2-3 hours)

EDIT:
It did again fail after few days :'( Randomly started to write characters on screen. Plugging it out and back again did the trick but here you go, if you have suggestions.
Found out it happens when the device is booted with the usb plugged in.